# Loading partial views in angular controller into empty document

Tags: angularjs, partial-views

Given an empty document with just the bare essentials, loading js files and stylesheet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="labApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/lab.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/local.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/superhero.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="labController">
  </body>
</html>
```

And an empty controller in lab.js:

```
angular.module('labApp', [])
  .controller('labController', function() {
    var lab = this;
  });
```

How do I go about loading a partial view into the body?
Am I supposed to do things like that manually, using jQuery, or is there some hidden facility in angular to load partials?

Comment: You might want to consider using ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Ah, yes, that seems like the missing cog.. Please add an answer so I can accept it ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by rendering different views with ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

When loaded into your application, you can include it like this in

```
angular.module('app', [ui.router])
```

When you follow the documentation it is pretty easy to setup different routes. Good luck!